# How can I add a text to each section's header?

Tags: sectioning, header-footer

I got the section's name changing properly on each header, though the other text
`section.subtitle` remains the same on every page. How can I have another text
in the header for each section?

As dirty workaround I would rename each section, so `section.name` would become `section.name\nsection.subtitle`

I know this is way beyond a proper mwe, though I can't remember what every part's doing.

```
\usepackage{titlesec}%
\fancyhead[RO]{\underline{Authorname}\\~\\\leftmark\\section.subtitle}%

\documentclass[12pt,landscape,a4paper,titlepage]{article}%
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}%
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}%
\usepackage{lmodern}%
\usepackage{textcomp}%
\usepackage{lastpage}%
\usepackage{geometry}%
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}%
\usepackage[english]{babel}%
\usepackage{blindtext}%
\usepackage{xpatch}%
\usepackage{floatrow}%
\usepackage{caption}%
\usepackage{fancyhdr}%
\usepackage{titlesec}%
%
\xpretocmd{\section}{\thispagestyle{plain}}{}{}%
\pagestyle{fancy}%
\title{Jon Doe}%
\author{Authorname | MonthName YYYY}%
\date{}%
\rhead{Authorname}%
\fancyhf{}%
\fancyhead{}%
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}%
\fancyhead[RO]{\underline{Authorname}\\~\\\leftmark\\section.subtitle}%
\renewcommand\sectionmark[1]{\markboth{#1}{}}%
\titleclass{\section}{page}%
\assignpagestyle{\section}{empty}%
\titleformat{\section}[display]{\centering\Huge\bfseries}{\sectionname}{0pt}{\huge}[\clearpage]%
%
\begin{document}%
\normalsize%
\maketitle%
\section*{sectionName}%
\begin{figure}%
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth,height=3cm,keepaspectratio]{/demo}%
\end{figure}%
\pagebreak
\section*{otherSectionName}%
\begin{figure}%
  \includegraphics[width=\linewidth,height=3cm,keepaspectratio]{/demo}%
\end{figure}%
\end{document}
```

[image: img]

Comment: You could use the optional argument of \section*, but that would also change the TOC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not currently using `\rightmark` for anything else, so you could store the subtitle there.  However, you need to define it BEFORE `\sectionmark` runs.

```
\documentclass[12pt,landscape,a4paper,titlepage]{article}%
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}%
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}%
\usepackage{lmodern}%
\usepackage{textcomp}%
\usepackage{lastpage}%
\usepackage{geometry}%
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}%
\usepackage[english]{babel}%
\usepackage{blindtext}%
\usepackage{xpatch}%
\usepackage{floatrow}%
\usepackage{caption}%
\usepackage{fancyhdr}%
\usepackage{titlesec}%
%
\xpretocmd{\section}{\thispagestyle{plain}}{}{}%
\pagestyle{fancy}%
\title{Jon Doe}%
\author{Authorname | MonthName YYYY}%
\date{}%
\rhead{Authorname}%
\fancyhf{}%
\fancyhead{}%
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}%
\fancyhead[RO]{\underline{Authorname}\\\vskip\baselineskip\leftmark\\\rightmark}%
\renewcommand\sectionmark[1]{\markboth{#1}{\mysubtitle}}%
\titleclass{\section}{page}%
\assignpagestyle{\section}{empty}%
\titleformat{\section}[display]{\centering\Huge\bfseries}{\sectionname}{0pt}{\huge}[\clearpage]%
%
\newcommand{\subtitle}[1]{\gdef\mysubtitle{#1}\ignorespaces}
%
\begin{document}%
\normalsize%
\maketitle%
\subtitle{First subtitle}
\section*{sectionName}
\begin{figure}%
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth,height=3cm,keepaspectratio]{/demo}%
\end{figure}%
\pagebreak
\subtitle{Second subtitle}
\section*{otherSectionName}
\begin{figure}%
  \includegraphics[width=\linewidth,height=3cm,keepaspectratio]{/demo}%
\end{figure}%
\end{document}
```